# Welche Argumente gibt es, Numeralia zu den Artikeln zu zählen? Sind sie syntaktisch ähnlich wie Demonstrativpronomina?

Tags: adjective, numbers, word-classes

Auf [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortart#Aufgabe_der_Wortart_Numeralia) steht:

> Mitunter wird die Selbständigkeit einer Kategorie *Numeralia* verneint [1], und diese werden dann den Adjektiven zugeschlagen [2]. Bleibt es dabei, hat man eine weitere *Neun-Wortart-Lehre,* bei Wegfall auch des Artikels eine *Acht-Wortart-Lehre.*

Welche Argumente gibt es, die dafür oder dagegen sprechen?

- Zwischen zwei gleichgestellten, gleichrangigen Adjektiven wird ein Komma gesetzt [3]. Jedoch müssen Numeralien zwangsläufig vor dem attributiven Adjektiv stehen. Können sie folglich nicht als gleichrangige Adjektive bezeichnet werden, weil dort auch kein Komma hinkommen kann? Und sind sie folglich gar keine Adjektive?

  Andererseits stehen natürlich auch Adjektive wie *gesamt* immer *vor* anderen, weiteren Adjektiven. Dort könnte zwischen *gesamte* und *bezogene* auch *Menge* eingeschoben werden:

  - die gesamte bezogene [Menge] Energie
  - die gesamte bezogene [Menge] Schleifnormalkraft
  - ...

Könnte man also auch argumentieren, dass die Numeralia, weil sie immer vor den anderen attributiven Adjektiven stehen, also eher einem Demonstrativpronomen ähnlich kommen? Dann könnten sie also genauso gut auch zu den Demonstrativpronomen oder Artikel gezählt werden?

[1] Duden, *Rechtschreibung und Grammatik – leicht gemacht.* 2007, S. 127.
[2] Gabriel/Meisenberg: *Romanische Sprachwissenschaft.* 2007, S. 190.
[3] [Duden: Komma zwischen zwei Adjektiven.](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/komma-zwischen-adjektiven)

Comment: Einer der seltenen Fälle, wo ich +1 gebe, aber für Schließen plädieren muss. Wie der Wikipedia-Artikel schon ganz gut darlegt, gibt es keine “richtige” Einteilung der Wortarten. Wortarten sind künstliche Schubladen, die den vollen Reichtum der Sprache nicht erfassen können, sondern nur das allermeiste. Wie man so ein Schubladensystem wählt, ist letztlich Geschmackssache und hängt auch ein wenig davon ab, wofür man die Schubladen braucht (die Einteilung in Wortarten ist schließlich kein reiner Selbstzweck). Deswegen: *Primarily opinion-based.*

Comment: Mir geht es darum, ob die Numeralia, weil sie immer vor den anderen attributiven Adjektiven stehen, nicht automatisch eher einem Demonstrativpronomen ähnlich kommen. Ob sie also genauso gut auch zu den Demonstrativpronomen oder Artikel gezählt werden könnten.

Comment: Dann schreibe Deine Frage dahin um. Zum Beispiel »Welche Argumente gibt es, Numeralia zu den Artikeln zu zählen?« halte ich für eine gute und berechtigte Frage.

Comment: "Jedoch müssen Numeralien zwangsläufig vor dem attributiven Adjektiv stehen." - würde ich so nicht unterschreiben. Wenn die gezählten Dinge als eine Einheit verstanden werden, kann das Adjektiv durchaus davor stehen. Nicht nur die heiligen drei Könige, sondern auch die weltberühmten sieben Zwerge lassen grüßen.

Answer (score 1):

***Ein*** Argument dafür, Numeralia zu den Artikeln zu zählen, siehst du fettgedruckt am Beginn dieses Satzes. Während manche – auch germanische – Sprachen zwischen unbestimmtem Artikel und der Zahl 1 unterscheiden, wird im Deutschen immer nur der unbestimmte Artikel für genau *einen* Gegenstand verwendet – und sogar mitgebeugt.

> I bought *a* dog and *one* cat yesterday. I saw *a* dog’s leash and *one* tree’s leaf lying in the park. *One* of my two dogs is black. *A* cat’s fur is soft.
>
> Ich habe gestern *einen* Hund und *eine* Katze gekauft. Ich habe die Leine *eines* Hundes und das Blatt *eines* Baumes im Park liegen gesehen. *Einer* meiner Hunde ist schwarz. Das Fell *einer* Katze ist weich.

Die Beispiele verdeutlichen, dass im Deutschen immer *ein/e/r/n/s* anstelle von 1 (*eins*) steht, selbst wenn man *genau eins* meint, während im Englischen eine Unterscheidung zwischen dem Artikel *a(n)* und der Zahl *one* getroffen werden kann. Niemand kauft **eins Katze.*

Dieser Dualismus ist im Singular deutlicher als im Plural, denn man stölpert selten über unbestimmte Pluralartikel im Deutschen. Als Beispiel diene mir *einige,* das Adjektive stark beugt, wie es unbestimmte Artikel im Singular tun.

> Zwei schwarze Hunde sind um die Ecke gelaufen.
> Einige schwarze Hunde sind um die Ecke gelaufen.
> Die schwarze**n** Hunde sind um die Ecke gelaufen.
>
> Die Leinen zweier schwarzer Hunde hängen dort.
> Die Leinen einiger schwarzer Hunde hängen dort.
> Die Leinen der schwarze**n** Hunde hängen dort.
>
> Ich werfe zwei schwarzen Hunden einen Ball zu.
> Ich werfe einigen schwarzen Hunden einen Ball zu.
> Ich werfe den schwarzen Hunden einen Ball zu.
> (Formengleich)
>
> Ich rufe zwei schwarze Hunde.
> Ich rufe einige schwarze Hunde.
> Ich rufe die schwarze**n** Hunde.

Ich finde, dass damit ausreichend Parallelen zwischen unbestimmten Artikeln und Numeralia aufgezeigt sind, um die Zuordnung letzterer zu ersteren zu gestatten. Gleichzeitig ist es mir nicht entgangen – insbesondere dadurch, dass Adjektive formgleich sind, egal ob ein unbestimmter Artikel davorsteht oder nicht –, dass man die gleichen Argumente benutzen könnte, um unbestimmte Artikel den Zahlworten und diese den Adjektiven zuzuschlagen.

---

Exkurs: Nicht in allen Sprachen werden Numeralia so behandelt wie im Deutschen. Japanisch kennt zum Beispiel keinen Plural, demnach kann ein Zahlwort ein Substantiv nicht in den Plural versetzen. Finnisch, wiederum, kennt Singular und Plural und einen besonderen Kasus für unbestimmte Substantive, den Partitiv. Auf Finnisch zwingt ein Zahlwort das zugehörige Substantiv automatisch in den Partitiv Singular. Beispiele:

> Näin auton. — *Ich sah ein Auto.*
> Näin sen auton. — *Ich sah das Auto.*
> Näin autoja. — *Ich sah Autos (unbestimmt).*
> Näin ne autot. — *Ich sah die Autos.*
>
> Näin 2 (kaksi) **autoa.** — *Ich sah zwei Autos.* Im Singular, vgl.
> Odotan **autoa.** — *Ich warte auf ein/das Auto.*